# Use of ip-hider software on VPS

Tags: vpn

I am using an unmanaged vps to play a morph game.  6 cores, 30gb, 2000 GB ram, 1gbit/s port.

I want to log into the game site with a browser but I don’t want the game site to see my server’s ip address.

I installed a vpn-ip hider program on the server but when in operation it consumes 45 to 50% of cpu.  How do I use WS2012 R2 to adjust my settings so the ip-hide program uses 8 to 9% of cpu as it does on my home computer?